# Spreading and passing object as props not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a bunch of Text components like

```
 <Text style ={{...style.additional, ...applicationTheme.label}} numberOfLines ={1}>Some Text</Text>
```

I want to put the props in variable as in below but not working. Any thought?

```
const textProps = {numberOfLines: 1, style:{...style.additional, ...applicationTheme.label}};

  <Text {...textProps}> SomeText </Text>
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean when you say it's "not working"?  Be specific please.

Comment: The above text does not work as expected. The styles are not applied

Answer (score 3):

Seems normal, try the in-text demo:

```js
const App = () => {
  const styleA = {
    backgroundColor: 'lightblue',
  }
  const styleB = {
    color: 'red'
  }
  const text = 'TEST';
  const props = {id: text, style: {...styleA, ...styleB}};
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 style={{...styleA, ...styleB}} id={text}> style is normal</h1>
      <h2 {...props}>...props is normal too</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```